# Unable to Create New Set From Array

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create new Sets from an array but it is returning an empty object. What am I doing wrong?

```
const myArray = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value1", "value2"];
const mySet = new Set(myArray);
Logger.log(mySet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Set()` returns the Set object. When you want to see the value, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Logger.log(mySet);
```

#### To:

```
Logger.log([...mySet]);
```

or

```
Logger.log(Array.from(mySet));
```

#### References:

- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)