# Apps Script only consider first submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to update a spreadsheet in real time while form submissions are coming into the sheet. To do this, I have created a set to hold all ID's that have already submitted in order keep track of whether or not a new submission should be counted or not. However, I am having some trouble with sets in Apps Script. [image]

For whatever reason, the log shows that `s8` is still empty -- `{}`. I am not sure why this is the case. It may be important to note that these statements are outside of any functions, and that the only time any functions are called is when a form is submitted.

Is there any way to fix this? If not, is there another way to ensure that only the first submission for each ID is counted?

Comment: I think that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75551571 In your script, please modify `Logger.log(s8);` to `Logger.log([...s8]);` or `Logger.log(Array.from(s8));`, and test it again.

Comment: Thanks! This allows me to actually see the contents of the set. The log statement here is saying that the set contains `1234.0` instead of `1234`, though -- any ideas how to fix that? Also it seems that the values in the set reset after each form submission. How can I prevent this? I want the values in the set to stay.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Thanks! This allows me to actually see the contents of the set.`, I understood that your question was resolved. By this, I flagged it as a duplicate question.

Comment: About your new questions of `The log statement here is saying that the set contains 1234.0 instead of 1234, though -- any ideas how to fix that? Also it seems that the values in the set reset after each form submission. How can I prevent this? I want the values in the set to stay.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new questions.

Comment: No problem. Consider set `s8`. After one form submission, say that it is equal to `{1234}`. After another form submission, say that I am adding `2345`. Then `s8={2345}` -- the initial `1234` is gone!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your reply, I found it as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76800291 and I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.